# Errow while openning ubuntu 20.04 software & updates

Tags: updates

I am having a problem with ubuntu after i removed all postgresql files. When i open software and updates it opens as ablank screen. any solution to that? [image]

Comment: Obvious question... why did you remove postgresql?

Comment: i installed it and it version 12 and it wasnt working. So i decided to remove then install it afresh. I am getting more issues which need to be solved.

Comment: What other issues? Update your question with more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)