# Ubuntu Software not loading properly

Tags: software-center, 20.04

In my freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Ubuntu Software is not loading properly.

It is loading only `Editor's Picks` but nothing else.
Installed tab is empty and search is not working as well.
My internet connection is perfectly working and I am not using any firewall.

Comment: This answer worked for me https://askubuntu.com/a/1284673/1148590

Answer (score 177):

On Ubuntu 20.04LTS the app called "Ubuntu software" is in reality snap-store (the terminal command running it is "snap-store", not "gnome-software"). Ubuntu 20.04 does not seem to come with gnome-software installed by default. For me, closing the app, then typing

```
killall snap-store
```

in a terminal and then re-launching the app solved the problem without a reboot.

Comment: Solved the issue

Comment: This solved the issue for me, thanks so much @arnaud

Comment: For me closing the snap-store using System Monitor also worked.

Comment: For me it was also the solution.

Comment: Or type it in Alt + F2

Comment: This also works for me. But I wonder why the original problem happens tho at the first place?

Answer (score 20):

If all images and software aren't loading in the software app delete the ubuntu-reviews.db file at `~/.local/share/gnome-software/ubuntu-reviews.db`. It will be recreated automatically the next time you open Ubuntu Software (the Software app). Open the terminal and type:

```
killall gnome-software
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gnome-software/
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-software/
mv ubuntu-reviews.db ubuntu-reviews.db.bak # skip if ubuntu-reviews.db doesn't exist
```

Then reopen the Software app.

If it still doesn't work you could try reinstalling the Software app.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge gnome-software
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: `gnome-software: no process found` I am getting this.

Comment: That means that Ubuntu Software is already closed, so continue to the next command.

Comment: No such file or directory `~/.local/share/gnome-software/`, please note: I am using 20.04

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: gnome software is not installed by default on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. What is referred to as "Ubuntu Software" in the app list corresponds in fact to the terminal command snap-store.

Answer (score 17):

In Ubuntu 20.04, it is installed as a snap package named `snap-store` (not as debian package).

Reinstalling the snap package solved the issue for me. For me it wasn't opening at all.

```
snap remove snap-store
snap install snap-store
```

Comment: removing and reinstalling snap-store fixed the problem for me.

Comment: worked for me too

Comment: thanks worked for me

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that has worked so far is

```
gnome-software refresh
```

But the terminal has to be kept open.  Once it is closed, the apps disappear again.

**Update:** [G. Koçmarlı](https://askubuntu.com/users/773211) has [posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284673/1148590) a working solution on [Ubuntu software shows only editors picks 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1248599/).

Answer (score 10):

If you're getting unresponsive search, try reinstalling the software center.

```sh
sudo apt reinstall gnome-software
```

Comment: It says: `Package gnome-software is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`

Answer (score 9):

All I did was use the command:

```
gnome-software refresh
```

and it worked.

Comment: No matching snaps for "gnome-software"

Comment: Sorry guys who downvote this answer, but this was the only one that works for me. So I upvote this.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I also freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 and was having problems with Ubuntu Software.

Run

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: I started testing the answers beginning from the simplest ones. This was the second answer tested and the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of installing the gnome-software try:

(Ubuntu has this by default but still you may not have it)This installs the snapd package manager wich ubuntu software uses

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

This installs the snap store using the package manager

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo snap install snap-store
```