# Ubuntu software shows only editors picks 20.04

Tags: software-center, 20.04

Hey fantastic community :)

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a problem with the Ubuntu Software app only showing the editors picks. It finds stuff i search for, but I like browsing for it.

This was fine when the install was fresh, but after the update it broke.

Interestingly this isn't the first time it has happened to me, also did the same with 18.04, but last time I was not able to fix it. Any help is good.

Superthanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Well.... this is .. something. Thinking the only thing that is different from the original install is that I am using the unite extension as well as dash to dock, I disabled them and re-enabled them, logged out and logged in again. It's good again now. Really weird.

Comment: This might not be a permanent fix though. so if any thoughts.. please come with them

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, it worked on my computer. The main purpose of this solution is finding the "Software" app and use it.

1. Open Ubuntu Software application.
2. Then click Ubuntu Software on top bar, choose "Show Details".
3. It'll open a new software app which will show you error: Sorry, there are no details on that application. Close error. This app must have the categories section and lots of applications.
4. Find the icon on left favorites panel and left-click the bluish icon which named only "Software.
5. Press "Add to Favorites". You'll need to use it when you want to install an app.

Comment: There is no "Show Details" Button