# Adjusting software management apps in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center

[image]
[image]

I misedited this file and now I have two "Ubuntu Software" apps. In fact the original Ubuntu Software had disappeared suddenly but it was available after I logged in today, however it is broken. Thus I wish to get the Software GNOME icon back and fix the Ubuntu Software app too.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Software app desktop icon file for editing in nano text editor.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Software.desktop
```

Edit the file in nano text editor so that it looks like this. The required changes to `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Software.desktop` are highlighted in bold text.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Software
Comment=Add, remove or update software on this computer
# Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon file name)!
Icon=org.gnome.Software
Exec=gnome-software %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;PackageManager;
# Translators: Search terms to find this application. Do NOT translate or localize the semicolons! The list MUST also end with a semicolon!
Keywords=Updates;Upgrade;Sources;Repositories;Preferences;Install;Uninstall;Program;Software;App;Store;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/appstream;x-scheme-handler/apt;x-scheme-handler/snap;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-software
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=gnome-software
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
DBusActivatable=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-software
```

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Logout and log back in again. If that doesn't work open the terminal and type: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-software && sudo reboot`

If the categories in the Software app aren't loading read the answers to [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238069/).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I also fix Ubuntu Software?

Comment: Logout and log back in again. If that doesn't work open the terminal and type: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-software && sudo reboot`