# Software app is not showing installed software and not installing .deb package

Tags: 20.04, deb, gnome-software

Earlier my software store was not showing installed software, but I referred to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly), but still it's not running the .deb package. I want to use Chrome Remote Desktop service. I followed the steps, downloaded the package, and installed it, but app center doesn't show that it is:

[image: snapshot]

[image: snapshot]