# Ubuntu Software App Shows Just Blank Tiles

Tags: gnome, 20.04, software-center

My desktop computer runs Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and Gnome 3.36.8 with German as the interface language. Since at least last week, Ubuntu Software shows just blank tiles instead of actual software information like this:

[image: Ubuntu Software App with blank tiles]

When I click the links, nothing happens, and clicking the Search button and searching doesn't find anything, so it's useless.

I tried turning the VPN off, but that didn't make a difference.

What questions or advice do you have?

Comment: Restarting `snap-store` by running [`killall snap-store`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291111) in the terminal worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running some standard update commands such as:

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```

and restarting, it worked again!

Comment: Could you please explain what the last two commands do?