# 20.04.2 Software Store Not Showing Installled Apps or Updates

Tags: updates, software-center, dropbox

Software Center was not showing any software (Explore), just blank tiles, and not showing anything more than an eternally whirling whirligig in the Installed tab, ditto for the Updates.

After running some standard update commands (per user Curtis Bryant) such as:

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

and

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f

and restarting, the tiles repopulated but that's all that changed. the whirligigs are still whirling for Installed and Updates.

at the moment all I want to do is remove mozilla vpn from my apps and perhaps reinstall dropbox since I no longer see its icon in the Desktop header assuring me it's in sync with the parent (its folder IS in the Home folder), but it would also be nice if the Software Store worked like it should. Thanks in advance, ubu-gurus. Feel free to critique my question.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64-bit, Gnome 3.36.8

Comment: Also tried the [same commands you tried](https://askubuntu.com/a/1315119), but it didn't help. Restarting `snap-store` by running [`killall snap-store`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291111) in the terminal worked for me.