# "ubuntu software" cannot search for software or updates - spinning wheel forever

Tags: update-manager

The Ubuntu Software update app has stopped working again. Same thing happened in 20.04 and now in 20.10. For example, when I click on the Updates tab, the spinning wheel with "Looking for new updates..." goes on forever. I did a manual update with the command-line ("sudo apt-get update"), which works fine. Another system I have running 20.10 runs Ubuntu Software fine. What could be wrong with this system? Where do I look? Thank you.

Comment: On stock Ubuntu 20.04, in Ubuntu Software, when I click any of the "featured" software's "tiles", or when I search for VLC, or when I check for updates on the updates tab, I also get just a spinner, forever. Tried looking in the logs but did not spot anything... All the while, System Monitor does not show even a blip of network activity. The thing is either utterly broken, or I have misconfigured something, like who may use "search"? But then it should put out a message saying that. So, yeah, broken or not, it's unusable.

Comment: This answer probably solves it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling the app worked for me, since the software catalogue is built on first launch.

```
snap remove snap-store && snap install snap-store
```