# Ubuntu software list is empty

Tags: software-center

Firstly, I am new here so apologies if this all seems a little noobish. I have just switched from Windows and started to use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.
Unfortunately, I have ran in a bit of a problem, for some apparent reason the "Ubuntu Software" seems to be completely blank other than the editor choice or recommended software or snaps? So, any help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update`?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you install the Synaptic package manager. Type `sudo apt install synaptic`, and you can run that program in addition to the software center and/or snap. Good luck :)

Comment: @ Bernt Ribbum, I have tried that, still no positive results. It's been three or four days and I am already starting to regret installing Ubuntu. It's just incapable of standing at part with windows or Mac IOS. That's just the crux of it.

Comment: @Sidharath, that is unfortunate. Granted, Linux comes with less handheld support, and demands more reading/effort on your side. I also agree that the software offerings are not as polished, but once you get past that hurdle you're rewarded with a much more stable and secure system than any of the others!

Comment: Thannx for the Synaptic advice! I'm already using it.     
But sometimes, it's nice to have a display of packages offered.

Comment: I'm running Ubu 22.10 on an old laptop, and I also have this problem. The only things presented are the "Editors' Choices". The rest of the UBUNTU SOFTWARE choices are blank, except for the ubiquitous "..." implying something is happening.    ----

Comment: WAIT, WAIT! It took about 20 minutes, but the rest of the apps finally are starting to fill in.  !

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Software aka Snap Store shows only a few software picks on the front page and nothing more when there are access errors on snapcraft.io server, which recently happens quite often. To confirm that's the issue, you need to kill the runing `snap-store` process and re-run it in the terminal (see below how to do it). If you see any "access denied" errors in the output, then that's the server issue. This is a temporary problem that goes away when they fix the server and it starts to operate normally again.

Exact steps to do:

1. close the Snap Store application
2. open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
3. type the command: `ps -ef|grep snap-store|grep -v grep` to check if `snap-store` process is still running
4. if you get anything in the output, that indicates that `snap-store` is still running. The output may be like:

   raj        24225    1871  2 21:41 ?        00:00:23 /snap/snap-store/542/usr/bin/snap-store
5. in that case type the command `kill number` where `number` is the **first** number shown in the line above, right after the username (in this case 24225)
6. repeat step 3 to confirm that `snap-store` is not running anymore
7. type the command: `snap-store` and watch the output for "access denied" messages.

Comment: Also trying to run / install anything via snap will often give error message showing more useful info. For me, my ca certs were messed up. this is how I found out.

Comment: @raj I tried the [link]-ef|grep snap-store|grep -v grep **bold** command on terminal, however I received the [link] Command '-ef' not found, did you mean: command 'zef' from deb perl6-zef (0.8.2-1) **bold** I am unable to was able to see some applications using the [link] gnome-software refresh **bold** command but even then whenever I tried to install something from the gnome store it gave an error, the file is not supported.

Comment: @Sidharath You were supposed to use `ps -ef`, not only `-ef` alone. Where did you find that in my answer? Please follow the answer **exactly**.