# Ubuntu Software not showing categories

Tags: software-center, 21.04

I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't know too much. I installed Ubuntu to my laptop. Ubuntu Software is running version 3.38.1 and not showing categories. What should I do? I think I am running an old version of Ubuntu Software.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)

Comment: I would recommend to completely bypass Ubuntu Software and snap store. You can use the command `apt` to install software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu Software, a.k.a. Snap Store shows empty categories (or doesn't show categories at all, only a few software picks on the front page and nothing more) when there are access errors on snapcraft.io server, which recently happens quite often. You can find the error messages in system log, or you can kill the running `snap-store` process and run again `snap-store` in terminal. If you see "access denied" errors in `snap-store` output, then something happened again to snapcraft.io server. This is a temporary problem that goes away when they fix the server and it starts to operate normally again.