# Snap Apps no Longer displaying

Tags: snap

A few weeks ago, after an automatic update of the software, I noticed that the Ubuntu software was no longer being displayed. As to whether or not the system is using ZSH or not I have no knowledge. I have only used what was there. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to correct the problem? I followed some instruction that I've found on the net. But that was unsuccessful.

Comment: We don't know your OS & release, nor do we know why you mention `zsh` (it's not a default so mention it??) What instructions did you follow?  (your command history will provide clues; if not other logs (eg. apt logs if you installed *deb* packages etc).  Currently we don't know enough to provide any meaningful help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)