# Apparmor problem with snap-store? Ubuntu software not working properly 20.04

Tags: software-center

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. 
I attempted to install apps from the Ubuntu software center, but it isn't working correctly.

1. No icons are displayed. [image: https://ibb.co/Rc4BmF0]
2. No screenshots or information about the applications are displayed. [image: https://ibb.co/GRWCmQm]

I tried [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly/) but it didn't work. 
How to fix?

```
[ 7740.813470] audit: type=1400 audit(1641719624.368:91): apparmor=&quot;STATUS&quot; operation=&quot;profile_load&quot; profile=&quot;unconfined&quot; name=&quot;snap.blender.blender&quot; pid=12796 comm=&quot;apparmor_parser&quot;

[ 7740.813479] audit: type=1400 audit(1641719624.368:92): apparmor=&quot;STATUS&quot; operation=&quot;profile_load&quot; profile=&quot;unconfined&quot; name=&quot;snap-update-ns.blender&quot; pid=12795 comm=&quot;apparmor_parser&quot;

[ 8529.948443] perf: interrupt took too long (5343 &gt; 5252), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 37250

[ 9331.941196] audit: type=1326 audit(1641721215.520:93): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=14223 comm=&quot;snap-store&quot; exe=&quot;/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store&quot; sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fb1dcf0489d code=0x50000

[ 9538.128342] audit: type=1326 audit(1641721421.710:94): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=14475 comm=&quot;snap-store&quot; exe=&quot;/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store&quot; sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fdcec47389d code=0x50000
```

Comment: Try this; HOLD `CTRL`+`ALT` and hit `T` - this should normally open a Terminal (with Bash prompting for commands). Type `dmesg | less` and then hit `>` to make "less" go to the very end of the text... now scan backwards (cursor up, page up) and look for "error", "failed" and similar... if you find any then edit your posting above and add the information there. This will help readers here analyze what the actual problem is. NOTE: You might need to actually run "Ubuntu Software" at least once to see any errors.

Comment: there isn't any error message about snap-store or ubuntu store only errors like (device not accepting address 10, error -71) but there are a lot of snap-store message. should I copy paste those?

Comment: The snap-store messages might contain a clue; "Ubuntu software" does have a "close" snap store relation. Include the text and make it be "code" (mark text, click `{}`)

Comment: I've updated them, most of them are similar to the ones above

Comment: You might have found the culprit; I'm not sure how to fix it though, somone who knows more about snap / apparmor needs to see this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has existed for a long time. Ubuntu's Snap store isn't well-maintained and doesn't perform properly. As a result, in *Jammy* 22.04, they've chosen to use Gnome software instead. Gnome software is working fine without any issues. You can install gnome-software using:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-software
```

If you want to remove the Ubuntu software app:

```
$ sudo snap remove snap-store
```

Gnome software is way better than the default application centre. The user interface is nearly the same.

**Note**: Ubuntu Snap Store is a re-designed version of Gnome-Software but unfortunately with bugs.

---

You can launch gnome software using:

```
 $ gnome-software
```

You can also launch it using the application overview.

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Gnome software Icon]

Here is the UI of Gnome Software in Ubuntu 21.10:

[image: Gnome Software UI]

You can install additional plugins for it too. For example, you can run the following command to enable the `snap` plugin in Gnome Software:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

If you want to enable flatpak support then you can run:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

Comment: Are snap apps available in this version of GNOME software?

Comment: You can install the plugin using `sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap`

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: Excellent solution!