# Ubuntu Software - hands on search

Tags: software-center, 21.10

I currently can't search any applications on 'Ubuntu Software'. I realize that apt is a workaround, but I like the experience of the GUI.

The syslog doesn't seem to show any related errors.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: the problem is with Ubuntu Snap Store, consider replacing it with gnome-software, Take a look at this question:[Apparmor problem with snap-store? Ubuntu software not working properly 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386114/apparmor-problem-with-snap-store-ubuntu-software-not-working-properly-20-04)

Comment: There are many alternatives; `muon` & `synaptic` package managers, Software Boutique & other stores etc...

Comment: @guiverc that may be, but I'm specifically interested to fix _this_ program. It's a default program and I'm invested in trying!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question; if you're asking about the `snap-store` you can run it from terminal and hopefully get some clues (snap packages run *confined* so messages may not appear in normal logs).  I just installed & ran it; and messages appear in various colors; errors in rather obvious red.  Sorry I have little experience with `snap-store` (I'm *mostly* involved with  *flavors* that don't come with snaps installed so don't diagnose snap issues often)

Comment: @guiverc `snap-store` seems to work today for some reason! I guess ill try running with `--verbose` next time I run into this. Thanks!

Comment: The `snap-store` seems to have issues on occasion; someone reports it, it gets fixed etc.. I'm glad it works for you.