# Snapd User Session Agent (2)

Tags: 20.04

I am relatively new to Linux and am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. A while ago two buttons (see image below) appeared at the bottom of my login-screen and they are not going away. I looks like I have to take some kind of action, but I am absolutely clueless as to what and how.

Can anybody give me an explanation?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like two snap daemon is waiting for some action from you. In my case, Skype & Vscode Snap package updating notifications telling me to close those programs to start updating process (Check your notifications). And also check if there is any other unwanted daemon running or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related to snap-store. The solution was to remove snap-store as explained by https://askubuntu.com/a/1386132/1626080.