# Snapd User Session Agent notification

Tags: 22.04, snap, snap-store

I am aware of this discussion: [Snapd User Session Agent (2)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414760/188970). I keep having this notification on my login screen:

[image]

I did a `sudo killall snap-store` followed by `sudo snap refresh snap-store` and everything is up-to-date. And I keep having this strange notification anyway:

[image]

What's going on in 11 days ? (yesterday, that was 12 days). My PC is going to explode :-) ? I turn off my computer every night. No seriously, it's annoying because I've checked all snap packages with `sudo snap refresh --list` and everything is up-to-date. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: @user535733 because everything is up-to-date in my case. It's something else. Which happens only with my desktop computer, and not with my laptop computer which has exactly the same installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had to find and stop the user process that snapd started in order for the refresh to work:

```shell
# stop the system from restarting snapd
sudo systemctl stop snapd
# look for why refresh is failing
sudo snap refresh snap-store
# shows refresh wouldn't work because there was a running process
# kill user process started by snapd
sudo kill <processId from above>
# refresh the snap plugin
sudo snap refresh snap-store
# verify stapd was restarted
sudo systemctl status snapd
```

Comment: I had used `sudo killall snap-store`and `sudo snap refresh snap-store` ; next time I have the problem, I'll try your solution :-).