# When I login I get this icon on my dock everytime. Don't know how to remove, quitting it from the dock doesn't work. I am new linux user bdw

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I try quitting it with the menu bar and dock but it doesn't work.

I am attaching the screenshot for the dock icon which is present every time i login.

[image]

Comment: your imgur link is broken.  we cannot see the image you are referring to.

Comment: @ThomasWard it worked for me, so I edited it in.

Comment: I don't see any doc icons in that image

Comment: I see no 'dock' icons other than this "Snapd User Session Agent" and "Printers" but both tend to indicate *notifications* not 'dock icons'.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Interesting, it 404d when I tried accessing it.  Temporary glitch in the matrix I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate, but I am out of votes on this one:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414760/snapd-user-session-agent-2