# 'Ubuntu Software' app not loading on 22.04

Tags: software-center, 22.04

I see previous questions about this but none of the answers work and it has been suggested that it is a problem at 'Snapcraft'

If this is still a problem it is a pretty poor show - is there an alternative GUI for managing installed software (I am trying to uninstall something)?

When I click the icon I get a spinning wheel cursor pointer for about 10 secs and then it goes back to nornal and nothing happens. No relevant process is running.

/var/log/syslog shows this every time I try.

```
Aug 26 19:32:54 rogerco-Lite systemd[1149]: Started snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software.e6ad0127-fbf7-4d35-bdd4-89003368a151.scope.
Aug 26 19:32:54 rogerco-Lite systemd[1149]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug 26 19:32:54 rogerco-Lite snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[10276]: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-snap\x2dstore_ubuntu\x2dsoftware-10276.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

What does this mean please and how do I fix it?
This is 22.04.1 updated from 20.04 which was updated from 18.04. There were also some automatic system updates earlier today.

Any suggestions, anyone else got a problem with the 'Ubuntu Software' app?

Comment: I don't know, how to fix the problem with the Ubuntu Software application, but while it doesn't work, you could try Synaptic. It's also a GUI based software manager, but as far as I know, it only supports APT.
If it isn't installed yet: sudo apt update sudo apt install synaptic If you know the exact name of the package, you want to uninstall, you could also try: sudo apt purge [package name] sudo apt autoremove

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425880/edit) to include the complete output of `apt list dbus-user-session` and of `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and of `systemctl --user | grep snap`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)

Comment: @karel - yes `killall snap-store` fixed it for me

Answer (score 8):

In the terminal, type `killall snap-store` and hit ENTER

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are still experiencing the problem. On going issue. (sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software)

Answer (score 0):

And today it works. Most strange. I guess that the Synaptics thing is still flakey - since this has been going on for months perhaps it should be removed from Ubuntu in the next release and a more reliable package manager used as per @manolol suggestion.

Comment: There is a new Software Store for Ubuntu written in Flutter which seems to be better than the one included inside of Ubuntu. Maybe give it a try (https://github.com/ubuntu-flutter-community/software/releases)