# killall snap-store killed my snap store entirely [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: snap, ubuntu-store, killall

after following the same advice as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly) I entered `killall snap-store`. Few weeks ago this perfectly fixed the problem but now I am getting this [error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu2sW.png)

translation of last statement in error-message: Memory Access Error (Dump Written)

So I also tried following:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
sudo snap install snap-store
```

but the terminal still returns same error-message.

Comment: You didn't say which version you are using, but you could try re-installing Snap Store.  This link might help : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-snap-store-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop

Comment: Terminal just says it is already installed