# Apps not loading on newly Installed Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, firefox, software-center

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my old PC. After first boot, Firefox worked fine but later the app opens but the window doesn’t appear. The close and the enlarge function works. I tried installing Falkon and Opera. Falkon doesn't load while Opera turns into a black window and the close/enlarge button is working. At present a lightweight Netscape browser is functioning. My PC does not have a graphics card installed. I have installed Ubuntu to start learning Python.

This is the info that I get from terminal when I try to launch Firefox.

```
arun@arun-HCL-Desktop:~$ firefox
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
Gtk-Message: 07:19:00.037: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: failed to read data from glxtest, we may fallback to software rendering
[GFX1-]: 
No GPUs detected via PCI
```

Error image when I try to open the app by launching and by pressing Alt+F2:

[image: Please see the error image]

The screen starts to flicker when new apps are opened after opening Firefox:

[image: The screen starts to flicker when new apps are opened after opening Firefox.]

I tried reinstalling the Snap Store, reinstalling Ubuntu and solutions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly).

Comment: Thank you @user535733 I have edited my question.

Comment: Ubuntu will work very, very slowly in a computer with 1 GB RAM. Use a lightweight operating system like https://antixlinux.com/ instead

Comment: It is impossible for a computer to have both DDR1 and DDR2 RAM. Which do you have, and how much of it? Also, there is no such thing as an "Intel Pentium Core" processor. Sounds like your computer is much too underpowered/old to be running Ubuntu, regardless.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance @user535733, have added the output from terminal when I try to run firefox

Comment: Thank you for the information @ArchismanPanigrahi My PC has 3GB RAM, have installed 2GB RAM recently.

Comment: @Esther I am sorry for the confusion, I am not sure of the RAM type, but it has 3GB of RAM and an SSD installed. I have booted Ubuntu 20.04 and it runs quick.

Comment: Also, snap runs very slowly on old computers. Can you try installing firefox from apt and removing snapd? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466 And for better performance, use Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE instead of regular Ubuntu

Comment: Many thanks to you @ArchismanPanigrahi Your answer worked! I am able to use firefox. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know that it works now. However, as I said in the previous comment, regular Ubuntu is quite heavy for older computers. Switch to Ubuntu MATE (and remove snapd), it will run much faster.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes, your answer helped me to setup and understand ubuntu system better. Will switch to Ubuntu MATE. Thank you! :)

Comment: @karel Thank you for your response. I have installed Ubuntu MATE and the system is functioning properly. Installing the Firefox app as a debian package and purging snap helped.