# Software Centre doesn't work

Tags: xubuntu, software-center

Suddenly Software Centre is not working at all on Xubuntu 22.04.3
When I start it, I see I the startpage and categories and when I click them, there all empty and will not load. The internet offers many ubuntu solutions but all the solutions failed.
With Synaptic I removed the Gnome-software and re-installed it, with no succes.
I execute all the terminal assignments from this article `https://www.dz-techs.com/nl/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-fixes` and nothing works. Should I install an earlyer version of Xubuntu? Can someone advice me please.

Later this evening: I don't know how I came up with it, but in the hidden folders of the Home folder I found a .cache folder containing a gnome-software folder. I threw that folder away. This command had already been executed in the terminal at an earlier stage, but apparently that did not work, even though I did not see any error message. After deleting the gnome-software folder and starting the software center, a message appears that the softwarecenter must be started first. I click the Startup button and the software center shows the home page. The categories remain empty, but by clicking on a category often with the mouse it will eventually be loaded. After shutting down and restarting everything runs smoothly again. I can use the software center again.
The reason for this failure I don't know but problem solved.

Comment: try "rm -r ~/.cache/gnome-software/"

Comment: That's what I already wrote: I empty the cache.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)