# Launch software-center but 'explore' is blank and unable to see what is installed

Tags: package-management, software-center, snap

Tried:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

```
 rm -r ~/.cache/software-center
    rm: cannot remove '/home/ptosis/.cache/software-center': No such file or directory
```

sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt autoremove

```
 sudo apt-get install software-center
      E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

 sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
      E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

  sudo snap install snap-store
        snap "snap-store" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

---

QUESTION:
please give command line to use snap to remove and then install software-center if that is even possible.

Thank you.

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
64-bit
GNOME version 3.36.8
Windowing system X11

Software update says everything is up-to-date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)

Comment: I will save this answer for future use. I cold started this morning and prior to using  command line  the software-center launches fine now. Thank you for answering.