# Ubuntu software center never loads results or app details

Tags: software-center

The Ubuntu Software center isn't loading any search results or application details.

- When performing a search, the spinner is displayed indefinitely.
- When clicking on one of the apps on the Explore page, the app displays "Loading application details..." indefinitely.
- The "Installed" tab also displays a spinner indefinitely.

How to resolve this issue?

Using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

I've tried to re-install it, but getting this message,

```
E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try first:

> killall snap-store

Then relaunch the app. If not working, you should investigate this similar issue reported previously: [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly).