# Ubuntu Software app without icons

Tags: 22.04, software-center

After installing latest updates, the Ubuntu Software App runs without icons and all the tabs are not working (running, but not functioning).
It's Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

[image: Ubuntu Software App Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software not loading properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238069/ubuntu-software-not-loading-properly)